# How to place a fixed image inside of a Jumbotron (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have no clue what I am doing wrong with it. Everything is the same as what I have searched online. I have my normal jumbotron setup

```
<div class = "jumbotron">
    <div class = "container">
    </div>
</div>
```

and then in my css I use the tag

```
.jumbotron {

    background-image: url(insertimagehere)
}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: try giving your div an `id` instead and set that css to have your background image.

Comment: Personally, it works, give us your url() exact code. Try to put a ";" after it.

Comment: the exact code is
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url("../images/picture1.jpg");
}